# Select multi row in one column in separate

Tags: mysql, sql

i have table that following below structure.

```
id name lang
1|  Test | en 
1|  Тест | ru
```

now i wanna get in one row like this

```
id | name_en | name_ru
1  | Test | Тест |
```

How to get like this. im using mysql.

Comment: What you have tried so far? And why you want to do that? Currently you have *correct* DB structure, and you want to create *worse* structure.

Comment: why its correct please explain me . actually i dont have any idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below sql query,

```
SELECT id, t1.name AS name_en, t2.name AS name_ru
    FROM my_table AS t1 LEFT JOIN my_table AS t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.lang=en AND t2.lang=ru
```